# Segmentation Fault: 11 on small input for array/vector

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

There are several questions related to this error on stackoverflow, and I understand that its related to excess memory usage by the array, or when using pointers (I tried this with vectors aswell) but using a small array, it still shows this error. The same code earlier was running fine (for merge sorting an array).

My input was as follows:

> 5
>
> 9 8 1 2 4

Output:

> Segmentation fault: 11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

void merge(vector <int> ar, int l, int m, int r){
    int n1 = m-l+1;
    int n2 = r-m;
    
    int L[n1];
    int R[n2];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        L[i]=ar[l+i];
    }
    
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
    {
        R[j]=ar[m+j+1];
    }
    
    int i,j;
    i = j = 0;
    int k = i;
    
    
    while(i<n1 && j<n2){
        
        if (L[i]<R[j])
        {
            ar[k]=L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else if (R[j]<L[i])
        {
            ar[k]=R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
        
    }
    
    while(i<n1){
        ar[k]=L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        ar[k]=R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    
    
}


void mergesort(vector <int> ar, int l, int r){
    int m;
    m=r+(l-r)/2;
    if (l<r)
    {
      
        
        mergesort(ar, l, m);
        mergesort(ar, m+1, r);
        merge(ar, l, m, r);
    }
}

void print(vector <int> ar, int size){
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout<<ar[i]<< " ";
    }
    
    
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector <int> ar;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>ar[i];
    }
    
    print(ar,n);
    mergesort(ar, 0, n-1);
    print(ar, n);
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run this through a debugger?

Comment: Just so you're aware, `int ar[n];` is non-standard c++, and really shouldn't be used, even if your compiler allows it and can work with it. Also, you should give your variables better names if you're going to post your code here.

Comment: Yes, I ran it through a debugger.
I'll repost my code with better variable names and using vectors @Xirema

Comment: valgrind result: `Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8`

Comment: `m=r+(l-r)/2;` Are you sure?

Comment: Yes it is equal to (l+r)/2, m being the mid element, l being left index, r being the right index. @timrau

Comment: @RohanB - *Yes, I ran it through a debugger* -- You are not just supposed to "run it through the debugger".  Do you know what the debugger is supposed to help you do?  You can single-step through your code, executing one line at a time, watch variables, set breakpoints, etc.  If you're just starting the debugger and pressing "Run", then you're not doing anything except running your program "at full speed", no different if you were not using the debugger.  Given this fact, you did **not** debug your program using the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in part with `m=r+(l-r)/2`. When `l` is `0` and `r` is `1`, `(l-r)/2` is `0`. This makes `m` equal to `1`, `l` equal to `0`, and `r` equal to `1` and the `mergesort(ar, l, m);` call identical to the one it just worked through. The stack grows unbounded until you have a segmentation fault. One way to fix this which will also make your code more efficient is to merge the lists when the difference between `l` and `r` is below some threshold. Or, you can just swap the two elements when you get to the point where `l` and `r` differ by one, like so:

```
if (l - r <= 1) {
    int temp = ar[l];
    ar[l] = ar[r];
    ar[r] = temp;
    return;
}
```

Comment: From my testing to corroborate what @jcolemang is saying: any time that `l` and `r` differ by only one, OP's code starts spitting out bad values. Either it recurses infinitely (like you suggested) or it starts making `l` larger than `r`.